# HE-AAC Player (AAC+, AACPlus)

Tags: streaming, html5-audio, audio-streaming, aac

Is there an embedded player that exists that can handle the HE-AAC codec? This is not for Icecast or Shoutcast, it's for a stand alone website that has a HE-AAC (AAC+, AACPlus) stream.

I've tried JW Player, JPlayer and several others, but none support the AAC+ format.

Anyone have any ideas of what embedded play might work?

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Codec support is browser dependent, and as far as I know, HE-AAC support isn't out there at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else, we ended up using a third party player called FlowPlayer https://flowplayer.org/

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Flash itself doesn't support HE-AAC.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Flash supports HE-AAC (MPEG-4 Part 3) from version 9.0.115.0.

More on Flash supported codecs [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/supported-codecs-flash-player.html).

Comment: Flash does. I ended up using a third party video player called Flowplayer (https://flowplayer.org/) that works like a charm. Just reformatted so that it looks like a audio player and not a video player.